# rule setting for action after saving new comment

Tags: rules

I need some help for a rule setting for this scenario:

after saving a new comment
all the users who bookmarked the node by a flag
shall get an e-mail

So i tried to set:
- Event: "After saving a new comment"
- Conditions: "Node is flagged" as bookmarks - Node: "comment:node" - user on whose behalf to check: ??users who bookmarked the node?? 
- Action: "Send mail" to ??users with this condition = true (or users who bookmarked the node)??

I believe i think the wrong way.
What`s the right way to build the rule for this scenario?

Comment: Why you are believing that? If it works, great, you did the job right! Remember *["you should only ask (...) questions based on actual problems"](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so as long as you don't have any errors, everything works and you can't tell what you are afraid of, we can't really answer here.

Comment: But it doesn`t work. So i think i'am wrong. I would never post a question if i know the answer!
So if i think the right way, i miss some tokens for: "users who bookmarked the node". i only have [site:current-user]. Which token shall i use?

Comment: If it does not work and found it not working, please edit your question to make it clear, describing it in a more obvious way ;) We are not evil guys who want to kick you, we try our best to understand you enough to provide an answer.